# Solving motivation issues caused by abuse

Tags: motivation, procrastination

I remember something in psychology saying some people who are motivated by parent/guardian abuse in their past can have issues motivating themselves unless under pressure of a deadline or other stressor. Is there a known disorder under these traits? What are some treatments that may work? And finally are there any books or readings on the topic.

Comment: Can you provide a link or reference that supports this claim?  This sounds like ordinary procrastination to me (which is not a disorder), and I don't know what would be special about a type that results from abuse, so a reference would be helpful.